# component isn't refresh when mapStateToProps is called on redux [DONE]

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I started from today to use redux, (I was on reflux) and there are some things i don't understand.
Well, i'm trying to create a todolist to understand the functioning of redux. Fetching work, but when i would like to delete a todo, i call an action, who send request to delete in database and remove todo's object in my array object of todo.

in my function mapStateToProps, the new state is changed but my component isn't refresh.

I look for an hour in various ways, but I do not understand do you have an idea?

**EDIT** : I have not returned a copy of my state in my reducer and that's why it did not work. **IMPORTANT** : not directly changed your reducer's state ;)

that's my code :

src/components/index.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchTodolist } from '../actions/todo-actions'

import Todo from './todo'


class Index extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchTodolist()
    }

    renderTodoList(){
        var tmp = this.props.todolist.map((todo) => {
            return (
                <Todo key={todo.Id} content={todo.Content} id={todo.Id} />
            )
        })
        return tmp
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
            <ul className="list-group">
            {this.props.todolist.length > 0 ? this.renderTodoList() : 'Loading...'}
            </ul>

            </div>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        todolist: state.todo.list,
        errors: state.todo.errors
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchTodolist: fetchTodolist})(Index)
```

src/components/todo.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { deleteTodo } from '../actions/todo-actions'

class Todo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    onDeleteClick(){
        this.props.deleteTodo(this.props.id)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <li id={this.props.id} className="list-group-item">
            <span>{this.props.content}</span>
            <button className="btn btn-default">Update</button>
            <button onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this)} className="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
            </li>
        )
    }
}


export default connect(null, {deleteTodo: deleteTodo}) (Todo)
```

reducers/todo-reducer.js

```js
import { FETCH_TODOLIST, DELETE_TODO } from '../actions/todo-actions'
import _ from 'lodash'

const INITIAL_STATE = { 
    list: [],
    errors: undefined
}

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {

    switch (action.type) {

        case FETCH_TODOLIST:
              return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    list: action.payload.data.Todo,
                    errors: action.payload.data.ListErr
                })
        case DELETE_TODO:
            var tmp = state.list
            var index = _.findIndex(tmp, {'Id': parseInt(action.id)})
            tmp.splice(index, 1)
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                list: tmp
            })
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

thank you. :)

Comment: How are you changing state when at the reducer level? Are you returning new state or mutating old state? You might want to check out this issue in the github https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/585

Comment: no returning new state, but i've only put only component code because i receive new state in function mapStateToProps but that's not refresh component

Comment: yes i've check this issue before post this problem

Comment: Please post your reducer.  You are almost certainly mutating your state.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#react-not-rerendering.

Comment: @markerikson ok i've edit my post

Comment: @markerikson sorry you're right, i've not used slice() to copy my array :X

Comment: @Fantasim I just noticed that you rejected my edit, even though syntax highlighting isn't working. I'll editit it again this time (for the sake of readability) I recommend you accept it.